# Advise on Residency Visa for Brasilians in Portugal

Tags: australia, brazil, portugal

I'm looking for advice or help.

My GF currently is from Rio and currently lives and works in Portugal whilst i am living in Melbourne. We are planning for her to visit me here before we start the process of a permanent move. However, her residency visa in Portugal has expired and she will renew but  apparently there is a backlog in the system and I'm told she can leave Portugal but cannot reenter if she goes outside of Europe.

Does anyone have any information or advise than can share? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It’s not entirely clear what you are asking about. Has your girlfriend already applied to renew her residency? When did it expire? https://eportugal.gov.pt/noticias/novo-servico-de-renovacao-automatica-do-titulo-de-residencia

Comment: Unless I am missing something Australia does not seem to be relevant here.

Comment: @jcm The OP lives in Australia, and says they'd like her to visit him in Australia "before we start the process of a permanent move." Australia seems a pertinent tag.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica yes but isn't the question about a Portuguese residency visa and reentry into Portugal?

Comment: Yes, that's what the OP asked. But I think the background information regarding Australia as an emigration destination could have some relevance.